# CSV importing in mysql by python

Tags: python-2.7, import, directory, mysql-python

i need make a program a coding in python for  importing multiple CSV files from a specific directory and that i have to do that by using  LOAD INFILE command in mysql db

Comment: ok. then do it :-)

Comment: Do a little research, write some code, and when you have a specific coding issue come back and ask that question. Make sure your question includes a [mcve] of what you have tried. Please take a look at [ask].